# Searching for key words within a JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and I am currently trying to allow the user to search for keywords within the jokes (setup and punchline) they have previously created. If the user searches for a word within the current created jokes, then I aim to display both the setup/punchline of the joke/s from which the searched word was found.

I am also aiming to print an error stating 'No jokes match the search term' if the searched word can't be found in any jokes.

This is my code:

```
import json



def input_something(enter_message):
    while True:
        inputSomething = input(enter_message)
        if len(inputSomething) < 1:
            print("Invalid Input - Enter Something.")
        if len(inputSomething) >= 1:
            return inputSomething


data_list = []
try:
    with open('data.txt') as openfile:  
        data_list = json.load(openfile)
except:
    TypeError

print('Welcome to the Joke Catalogue Admin Program.')

loop = True

while True:
    print('\nChoose [a]dd, [l]ist, [s]earch, [v]iew, [d]elete or [q]uit.')
    choice = input('> ')


    elif choice == 's':

        Search_Term = input_something('Enter search term: ')



    elif choice == 'q':
        print('Quitting joke bot! See you next time!')
        loop = False
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid choice - Please only select from the options provided!")
```

As you can see the option [s]search is empty, that is because I am stuck here.

Comment: Please edit the question and enter the code in the code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should return a list of search results:

```
elif choice == 's':

    Search_Term = input_something('Enter search term: ').lower()
    print("List of jokes:")

    validIndexes = []

    for index, New_Joke in enumerate(data_list):
        if Search_Term in New_Joke["Setup"].lower() or Search_Term in New_Joke["Punchline"].lower():
            validIndexes.append(index)

    print("Search results:\n")
    for index in validIndexes:
        print(f"Index: {index} -- {data_list[index]['Setup']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler depends on wich fields you need to search:

```
result = filter(lambda j: s in j["Setup"] or s in j["Punchline"], data_list)
# do what you want with the outputed list
```

You can also use a comprehension:

```
result = [ r for r in data_list if s in r["Setup"] or s in r["Punchline"] ]
```

Additionally, i recommend you to use objects instead of dict, it would be simpler and cleaner.

Comment: glad to help can you mark it as resolved now ? thanks